# batch find/replace using sed or awk

Tags: find, grep, sed, awk, xargs

In every file with filename matching pattern1 I want to search for lines which start with pattern2, and add some string in a new line above those matched lines.

As a simple example suppose I'm searching recursively in .txt files for potato and I want to add 'spam' above, then the file /tmp/blah.txt

```
hello
potato
world
not potato
bye
```

would be transformed into

```
hello
spam
potato
world
not potato
bye
```

Sounds like a simple job for a shell wizard, what's the easiest way to achieve this?  I've tagged some of the tools that I think would be the usual suspects here but I'm open to other suggestions.  Bonus points if it can show me a preview diff before I confirm to modifying the files in place.

Comment: Do you want to also match "no potato"? Your question indicates that yes but your desired output shows you don't.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to because it was not at the start of the line

Comment: OK, answer edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would also do it in Perl:

```
$ for f in *txt; do perl -pne 'print "spam\n" if /^potato/' "$f"; done
hello
spam
potato
world
spam
not potato
bye
```

The `-p` flag causes perl to print each line of the input file. The `-n` means, "read the input file line by line" and apply the script given by `-e` to each line. Then, the script itself will print `spam` if the current line contains `potato` and will print each line. The result will be the string `spam` printed above the lines containing `potato`.

That will simply print out the new file without modifying it. If you then want to make the changes to the original file, use `-i`:

```
$ for f in *txt; do perl -i.bak -pne 'print "spam\n" if /^potato/' "$f"; done
```

That will create a backup file called `foo.txt.bak` for each processed file and apply the changes to `foo.txt`.

Comment: I believe `/potato/` should be `/^potato$/` otherwise it would also match the "not potato" line?

Comment: @OlivierDulac the OP said "lines containing potato" I _wanted_ to match the "no potato" line.

Comment: @OlivierDulac turns out you were right, thanks, answer edited.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would probably use perl for something like this, but you can achieve what you want in bash alone:

```
while read -r line ; do if [[ $line =~ "potato" ]]; then echo spam;  fi;  echo $line; done < file.txt
```

If you want to put the result into a new file:

```
while read -r line ; do if [[ $line =~ "potato" ]]; then echo spam;  fi;  echo $line; done < file.txt > /tmp/outfile.txt
```

Comment: I believe `$line =~ "potato"` should be `$line =~ "^potato$"` otherwise it would also match the "not potato" line?